# Converting const char to std::string for title

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am working with gnuplot.

In the header file I have the following function:

```
void PlotPath(Gnuplot& gp, const char* title, bool first_plot = true, bool last_plot = true);
```

Then, in the cpp file:

```
template <typename T>
void Path<T>::PlotPath(Gnuplot& gp, const char* title, bool first_plot, bool last_plot)
{
    std::vector<WaypointPath<T>> waypoints = GenerateWaypoints(5000);
    std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> plot_points(5000);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < waypoints.size(); ++i) {
        plot_points[i] = std::make_pair(waypoints[i].position[0], waypoints[i].position[1]);
    }

    if (first_plot) {
        gp << "plot" << gp.file1d(plot_points) << "with lines title '" << title << "',";
    } else {
        gp << gp.file1d(plot_points) << "with lines title '" << title << "',";
    }

    if (last_plot) {
        gp << std::endl;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is instead of using const char* title, I want to use std::string title. 
So what I did is as follows and it works but I was wondering whether there is a better way of achieving this task.

```
template <typename T>
void Path<T>::PlotPath(Gnuplot& gp, const char* title, bool first_plot, bool last_plot)
{
    std::vector<WaypointPath<T>> waypoints = GenerateWaypoints(5000);
    std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> plot_points(5000);

    // Convert const char * to std::string
    std::string string_title = title;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < waypoints.size(); ++i) {
        plot_points[i] = std::make_pair(waypoints[i].position[0], waypoints[i].position[1]);
    }

    if (first_plot) {
        gp << "plot" << gp.file1d(plot_points) << "with lines title '" << string_title << "',";
    } else {
        gp << gp.file1d(plot_points) << "with lines title '" << string_title << "',";
    }

    if (last_plot) {
        gp << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here, I am converting the const char* to std::string by creating another variable. But Is there a way of including the `std::string title` in the function argument itself ?

What I have done here is working fine but I am just searching for a more elegant way of solving this.

Thanking You in anticipation.

Comment: Hard to do without a definition of what you mean by "elegant". My suspect is that the problem is in your perception of what is elegant and what is not... this function being a template for example is highly questionable for MY definition of elegance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your argument `std::string`. `std::string` has a constructor that takes a `const char*` so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to convert. This code works perfectly well.

```
if (first_plot) {
    gp << "plot" << gp.file1d(plot_points) << "with lines title '" << title << "',";
} else {
    gp << gp.file1d(plot_points) << "with lines title '" << title << "',";
}
```